# How would I match a multiline "TODO" only if the line ends with a backslash?

Tags: java, regex

I want to do a "TODO" matcher that will match only one line unless the line ends with "\". For every line that ends with that (consecutively only), the next line is also included.

Examples:

Matches lines 1-2:

```
//TODO: line one \
//Line 2
//Not part of todo
```

Matches lines 1-3:

```
//TODO: line one \
//Line 2 \
//Not part of todo
```

Matches lines 1 only:

```
//TODO: line one
//Line 2 (but not part)
//Not part of todo
```

I tried doing this as a start, but it won't match the second line:

```
/(\b(todo|TODO)\b.*|\btodo\b.*\\(\r\n|\n)+$\/\/)/gm
```

Comment: From `[regex]` tag description: Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I added "Java" for the language.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `$` (immediately after checking of an EOL character)?

Comment: @doctorlove I was trying to match that the line ended in a backslash and newline, but that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^\/\/TODO:(?:.*\\\s*\n)*.*/gm`

This matches a line that starts with `//TODO:` and any following line as long as the line before it ends with `\`

demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/MNM1Oz/3

Comment: Sorry to add to this, but is there any way to allow for a tab or space before the `//TODO`?

Comment: I figured it out: `^[ \t]*\/\/TODO:(?:.*\\\s*\n)*.*`

Comment: looks good :) I was about to add the edit but you beat me to it